# PostgreSQL function to check two texts are exactly the same

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

Is there any `PostgreSQL` function are there to `implement = operator` for two texts
for example, 
If I've two texts 1.`'stackoverflow'` and 2.`'stackoverflow'` then

```
select a_postgres_func(`stackoverflow`,`stackoverflow`)
Result:1
```

and the case two is if 1.`'stackoverflow'` and 2.`'stackoverflow '` (a trailing space for `2`)

```
select a_postgres_func(`stackoverflow`,`stackoverflow `)
Result:0
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to use `=`?

Comment: `select trim('stackoverflow') = trim('stackoverflow ')` should do just fine for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PostgreSQL`'s *inbuilt* function called `texteq` for this:

```
 select texteq('stackoverflow','stackoverflow')
```